# How to display command line args from main method

Tags: java, methods, command-line, parameter-passing

I feel like I figured out the hard part and I can make the program work if I have everything in **main** however I am still struggling with methods at this point my instructions are: **Write a method named sumInts that can take a variable number of int arguments and return the sum of these arguments. The ints to be summed up must be entered as command line arguments. Command line arguments can be simulated in Eclipse. In the main method, display the ints that were entered on the command line. Then execute sumInts and display the sum it returns.**

I cannot for the life of me figure out how I am supposed to **call my method to have it print out the sum of my command lines** Below is my code.

```
public class CommandLineSum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("# of command line args: " + args.length);

        System.out.print("Command line args in order: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(args[i] + " ");

        }

        System.out.println("\nThe sum is: ");

    }

    public static int sumInts(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }
        return sum;

    }
}
```

My output is:

```
# of command line args: 9
Command line args in order: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
The sum is:
```

And I need it to be:

```
# of command line args: 9
Command line args in order: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
The sum is: 45
```

Comment: `System.out.println("\nThe sum is: " + sumInts(args));`

Comment: Well wow. Let me go slap myself with my book.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your method `sumInts()` from main(). Pass `args` as parameter.

And you will get desired result:

> System.out.println("\nThe sum is: " + sumInts(args));

Answer (score 0):

```
class A
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    { 
      A obj = new A(); // creating object
      obj.sumInts(args); // calling function
    }

    public static void sumInts(String[] arr) {
        int sum = 0;
        String outputString="";
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            outputString  = outputString+arr[i];

            if(i !=arr.length-1){
                outputString = outputString+", ";
            }
            sum += Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("Passing ["+outputString+"]");
        System.out.println("Sum  is "+sum);
    } 
}
```

### /*

Save as **A.java**
Compile: j**avac A.java**
Run: **java A 10 20 3040**
*/